# How I can use a method of a model in a custom HtmlHelper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, lambda, html-helper

I am programming using ASP.NET MVC 3 with Razor view engine. Here's what I'd like be able to do:

```
@Html.DisplayWithLabel(model => model.DisplayEventDate(), "When", "")
```

`DisplayWithLabel` is a custom HTML helper that shows something with a label.

Here's its signature (or at least what I think it should look like):

```
public static MvcHtmlString DisplayWithLabel<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, Func<MvcHtmlString>>> expression, string label, string cssClass)
```

Why I am using my model like this? Well I'd like to have extensions methods for my model that will help me format its data when it's necessary (instead of formatting data inside my model itself). For example to format the event date I have this extension method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DisplayEventDate(this MyEntity entity)
{
    return new MvcHtmlString(string.Format("{0}@{1}", string.Format("{0:D}", entity.EventDate),
                             string.Format("{0:t}", entity.EventDate)));
}
```

But when I try to browse the view I am getting an error saying that it's not possible to implicitly convert from `MvcHtmlString` to `Func<MvcHtmlString>`.

I tried to figure it out myself but I couldn't find a clue so please help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyMethodName<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression,
    string myText) {
    var exprValue = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, 
                      htmlHelper.ViewData).Model;

    var builder = new TagBuilder("label");
    builder.SetInnerText(myText + " " + exprValue.ToString());
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString());

}
```

Comment: Well you are right :) but in this particular case I'd like to use MvcHtmlString explicitly instead of TValue

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand. You can pass any type through TValue